# How to call exports.function from exports.function in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a controller function that is declared like this. Based on my comment for this function, I need to call a DB method to get the currentUser data, but I want to re-use an exports.function for that.

---

I want to call this `getme` function:

```
// Get the profile of the current user through JWT.
exports.getme = (req, res) => {
  db.User.findOne({
    where: { id: req.user.id },
    include: [
      {
        model: db.Role,
        as: "role"
      },
      {
        model: db.UserType,
        as: "userType"
      },
      {
        model: db.PushToken,
        as: "pushToken"
      },
      {
        model: db.StripeAccount,
        as: "stripeAccount"
      }
    ],
    attributes: defaultAttributes
  })
    .then(data => {
      res.send(data)
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
      res.status(500).send({
        message: "An error has occured while retrieving data."
      })
    })
}
```

from this `createStripeAccount` function.

```
// Create Stripe Account
// If there's no stripeAccount connected to the current user,
// only then will we attempt to call stripe's create.
exports.createStripeAccount = (req, res) => {
  stripe.accounts.create({
    type: 'express',
    country: 'US',
    email: req.user.email
  })
    .then(account => {
      console.log('Account: ', JSON.stringify(account))
      stripe.accountLinks.create({
        account: account.id,
        refresh_url: 'https://app.com/reauth',
        return_url: 'https://app.com/return',
        type: 'account_onboarding',
      })
        .then(accountLinks => {
          console.log('Account links: ', accountLinks.url)
          return res.send(accountLinks)
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log("Error fetching account links from Stripe: ", err.message);
          return res.status(500).send({
            message: err.message || "An error has occured while fetching account links from Stripe."
          });
        })
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log("Error creating Stripe account: ", err.message);
      return res.status(500).send({
        message: err.message || "An error has occured while creating Stripe account."
      });
    });
};
```

Comment: side note: This code would probably benefit from changing it to `async`/`await` style.

Comment: Thanks, @Tomalak Will do that, and I actually like that async/await thing style better. :D This then/catch was just the first one I learned in Nodejs.

Comment: For me, it depends. There are situations where I prefer promises, but here it seems appropriate to use `async`/`await`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the function first, export it later.

```
function getme() {
  // ...
}

function createStripeAccount() {
  // ...
  getme(...);
  // ...
}

exports.getme = getme;
exports.createStripeAccount = createStripeAccount;
```

Answer (score 0):

use `this.getme(...)` wherever you want to use inside `createStripeAccount` function.

Comment: There is no guarantee that `this` will refer to the expected/correct object in a function call.

Comment: Interesting. I did that this.getme(...), I haven't tested/ran it. But is Tomalak's answer below/above required to get me going? Define first then export later? Or will my code in my question suffice to use this.getme(...)?

Comment: I see. Just saw Tomalak's comment above.